# Seek in libarchive, how to reset header?

Tags: c++, stream, compression, libarchive

Is it possible to read decompressed file once again?

Let imagine I used `archive_read_next_header(a, &entry)`,
 and I read an unknown number of bytes using `archive_read_data(a, ptr_to_buffer, buffer_size)`. Right now I want to reset it and start reading again from the beginning. I trying to override `seekoff(std::streamoff off, std::ios_base::seekdir way, std::ios_base::openmode which)`. I understand that might be impossible to just seek inside decompressed data because of inner work of compression algorithms, and data is not stored anywhere except a limited number of bytes in libarchive internal buffer.

The idea is to just reset it all, and read `std::streamoff off` bytes, that way I could create backward seek. Forward seek would be easy, just read `std::streamoff off` bytes. It's really inefficient, but let's hope, seek won't be used much.

Whole structure `archive` was initialized that way:

```
archive_read_set_read_callback(a, read_callback);
archive_read_set_callback_data(a, container);
archive_read_set_seek_callback(a, seek_callback);
archive_read_set_skip_callback(a, skip_callback);
int r =  (archive_read_open1(a));
```

where container contains most of all `std::istream`, and callbacks are functions which manipulate that stream.

Template of what I would like to achive
`

```
std::streampos seek_beg(std::streamoff off) {
        if(off >= 0) {
            // read/skip 'off' bytes
        } else {
            // reset (a)
            // read/skip 'off' bytes
        }
        // return position
    }
```

`

also my underflow() method is implemented that way:
`

```
int underflow() {
        int r = archive_read_data(ar, ptr, BUFFER_SIZE);
        if (r < 0) {
            throw std::runtime_error("ERROR");
        } else if (r == 0) {
            return std::streambuf::traits_type::eof();
        } else {
            setg(ptr, ptr, ptr + r);
        }
        return std::streambuf::traits_type::to_int_type(*ptr);
    }
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Libarchive documentation, more precisely, [wishlist in libarchive wiki on GitHub says:](https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/wiki/WishList#Seek_in_archives)

> A few people have asked for the ability to efficiently "re-read"
>   particular archive entries. This is a tricky subject. For many
>   formats, the performance gains from this would be very modest. For
>   example, with a little performance work, the seeking Zip reader could
>   support very fast re-reading from the beginning since it only involves
>   re-parsing the central directory. The cases where there would be real
>   gains (e.g., tar.gz) are going to be very difficult to handle. The
>   most likely implementation would be some form of checkpointing so that
>   clients can explicitly ask for a checkpoint object and then restore
>   back to that checkpoint. The checkpoint object could be complex if you
>   have a series of stacked read filters plus state in the format handler
>   itself.

As I see seeking in archives with help of libarchive is not right now possible, so a solution to my problem was to remember all read data only if I have some suspicion that I would want to re-read it, and alternatively push it back to stream.